# Why is my MySQLi connection so slow?

Tags: php, mysql

It takes for my local system about 1 second to establish a MySQLi connection. Code:

```
$db = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'mydb' );
```

Why is it so slow? Is this normal? Can I improve it?

Comment: Could you tell us more about your system? What OS are you using for example..

Comment: are you use vm-ware for made local server?

Comment: If you are using windows, try `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Switch "localhost" to 127.0.0.1.

So, instead of:

```
$db = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'mydb');
```

Use:

```
$db = new mysqli( '127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pass', 'mydb');
```

Seeing as this question seems to be pretty popular and a lot of people would like to know [WHY this is happening](http://thisinterestsme.com/slow-mysqli-connection/):

> This is caused because the MySQL client will do an IPV6
>   lookup for the hostname. If this fails (and in this case, it obviously
>   does), it will then attempt to do an IPV4 lookup. Between the IPV6
>   (AAAA) lookup failing and the IPV4 (A) lookup succeeding, what we get
>   is a connection timeout cycle that lasts about 1-2 seconds.

Worth noting that this problem only seems to occur with Windows 7 and after. Before Windows 7, localhost resolution was handled by the hosts file, which came pre-configured with `127.0.0.1`

Comment: same here - but WHY? that's very furstrating!

Comment: @rmirabelle Word is it has something to do with how mysqli handles localhost and IPv6.

Answer (score 3):

As [suggested by Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140975/ado-and-msqli-connections-very-slow/11367649#11367649):

> I edited the Mysql my.ini to change the mysql service to only bind to
>   the IPV4 loopback adapter.
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> ...
> bind=127.0.0.1
> ```

Comment: I get [ERROR] unknown variable 'bind=127.0.0.1' on mysql-5.7.35-winx64 but it works using bind-address=127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to edit the hosts file, found under windows\system32\drivers\etc

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Use an editor with admin rights to uncomment 127.0.0.1.

Comment: This is the better answer because it's more preferable to fix the root cause of the problem instead of using the IP-equivalent to localhost. Every machine should know that localhost is itself.